# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException,when I use "spark-submit" with a new class name rather than "SimpleApp",

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wrote a spark program with scala,but when I use "spark-submit" to submit my project,I met the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

my .sbt file :

```
name:="Spark Project"

version:="1.0"

scalaVersion:="2.10.5"

libraryDependencies+="org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.0"
```

my .scala file's name is SparkProject.scala and in it object's name is SparkProject too.

```
/* SparkProject.scala */
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SparkProject {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "YOUR_SPARK_HOME/README.md" // Should be some file on your system
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
    println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
  }
}
```

my command to submit project is :

```
spark-submit --class "SparkProject" --master local[12] target/scala-2.10/spark-project_2.10-1.0.jar
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?
At last what make me confuse is when I try the example provide here [http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html],it runs well.But when I build a new project and submit it goes wrong.
Any help will be great appreciated.

Comment: I think you are missing the `package name` in the class name in your submit command. I guess in your project, your SparkProject.scala file has something like `package com.example` as its first line. If it is... then this means that the fully qualified name of your class will be `com.example.SparkProject` so you will have to use `-- class "com.example.SparkProject"`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh. Yeah ! You are right,this is just the thing I nedd.Thanks a lot.

Comment: You guys might want to put that as an answer, to avoid keeping this one as "unanswered" to other that are looking to help ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Adding package name worked for me.

My code is simple too:

```
package spark.wordcount

/* SimpleApp.scala */
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val infile = "/input" // Should be some file on your system
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("word count")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val indata = sc.textFile(infile, 2).cache()
    val words = indata.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey((a,b) => (a+b))
    words.saveAsTextFile("/output")
    println("All words are counted!")
  }
}
```

I tried to run spark-submit like this:
[root@sparkmaster bin]# ./spark-submit --class spark.wordcount.WordCount /opt/spark-wordcount-in-scala.jar  and it ran successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Removing package name works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error while running spark on windows and building with sbt.

I did not have the line "package xxx" (E.g package spark.wordcount) in the code. If you do not have any mention of "package xxx" in your code then executing the command

```
spark-submit --class "SparkProject" --master local[12] target/scala-2.10/spark-project_2.10-1.0.jar
```

should work as mentioned by @SarveshKumarSingh in the comment section of the question.

But I was getting the error for a different reason. The scale file I created in notepad was **SimpleApp.scala.txt**. When I saved it properly as **SimpleApp.scala** it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents,

I tried all the mentioned solutions -- which are all valid. 
In my case, I had made a change in package name after running
sbt package
Hence, I was getting the mentioned error. On recompiling i.e "$sbt package" it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For others who are still looking for solution. I tried all other answers but not work to me. It works for me when I remove double quotes on the class name. You can try 
spark-submit --class SparkProject --master local[12]